# Intuition for why the superposition of many independent renewal processes is well-approximated by a Poisson process

Tags: poisson-process, renewal-processes

I’m trying to get an intuition for why the superposition of independent renewal processes in equilibrium converges – locally, on small timescales – to a Poisson process. (I mean a general renewal process; that the superposition of Poisson processes yields a Poisson process is a special case of this.)

Let $(N_i(t))_{i=1\ldots n}$ be $n$ independent renewal processes with i.i.d. interarrival times $X$, with CDF $F$ and density $f$, and set $μ := \mathbb{E}(X)$. Suppose the interarrival time $X$ is not arithmetic. I’m interested in the interarrival time of the “merged” process $N(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n N_i(t)$.

Here is what I know:

A key result in renewal theory is that in equilibrium, the excess life of the process $N_i$ has CDF:

$$\mathbb{P}(E(t) \le y) \to \frac{1}{μ}\int_0^y [1-F(x)]\,dx$$

Therefore, in the superposition $N(t)$ in equilibrium, by taking the minimum over $N$ realizations of $X$, the interarrival time $Y$ has CDF:

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(Y \le y) &= 1 - \left(1-\frac{1}{μ}\int_0^y[1-F(x)]\,dx\right)^n \\
 &= 1-\left(\frac{1}{μ}\int_y^\infty[1-F(x)]\,dx\right)^n \\
\end{aligned}$$

Based on the references below, $N(t)$ converges to a Poisson process for $n\to\infty$, so for large $n$ it should be “approximately Poisson”, so that the interarrival time $Y$ should be “approximately exponential”.

In other words, I think the following holds, **but I’d appreciate your help explaining why this seems to hold or how fast the convergence happens**:

$$\mathbb{P}(Y \le y) \approx 1-e^{-λy}$$

Based on a few numeric examples I tried out, it seems $λ \approx \frac{n}{μ}$.

#### References

- [Cox, D. R., & Smith, W. L. (1954). On the Superposition of Renewal Processes. Biometrika, 41(1/2), 91. doi:10.2307/2333008](https://doi.org/10.2307/2333008)  – Original article studying this problem for the first time, and deriving the result. Specifically equations (30)+(31), and section 5 claims: *In particular, the interval between successive events tends to be distributed in an exponential distribution, as can also be proved directly from (31)*. I don’t understand how it can be proved directly from (31) and the paper omits the details.
- Kallenberg (1997), Thm. 14.18 (p. 266) has a proof, it’s short and not giving me a great intuition.
- There is also the [Palm–Khintchine theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palm%E2%80%93Khintchine_theorem) for which I’ve not been able to find a proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I acquired some intuition now, sharing what I learned. They key is to realize that in general, the superposition of many independent renewal processes does not converge to a Poisson process globally, just locally.

Feller Vol II 1968, XI.4 example (a), covers this topic and puts it thus:

> We require, roughly speaking, that the renewal epochs of each individual renewal process are extremely rare so that the cumulative effect is due to many small causes.

The paper [Superposition of many independent spike trains is generally not a Poisson process](http://people.physik.hu-berlin.de/%7Elindner/PDF/paradox.pdf) has a good explanation why one cannot in general hope to obtain a Poisson process globally, only on short time scales:

> Put differently, if the single spike train $x_n(t)$ is sparse enough compared to the time window $T$ for which we consider the superposition of point processes […] then on this short time scale $T$, the process $X(t)$ constitutes a Poisson process. This amounts in the frequency domain to
> ignoring the low frequency range[.]

---

Intuition: For a distribution function $F$ of the interarrival time, in many well-behaved cases, $F(ε)\approx 0$ for $ε \ll μ$. Then $1-F(ε) \approx 1$, and therefore:

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(Y>ε) &= \left(1-\frac{1}{μ}\int_0^ε [1-F(x)]\,dx\right)^n \\
&\approx \left(1-\frac{ε}{μ}\right)^n \\
&\approx e^{-εnμ^{-1}}
\end{aligned}$$

As an example, consider renewals with a Gamma density and $α=100, β=200$, so that $μ=\frac{1}{2}$:

[image: Illustration]